# How to make Fiddler listen to a website on port 81?

Tags: iis-7, web, fiddler

Is it possible to make Fiddler capture traffic for a website on port 81 using IIS7

Comment: Are you asking how to use Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure - Fiddler will capture all traffic going through WinINET.  You can also capture localhost traffic if you use `http://ipv4.fiddler:NNN` as your server instead of `http://localhost:NNN` (where :NNN is the port that you're connecting to).

I don't believe (or at least I haven't found a way) to have Fiddler **only** capture a specific port for a specific host (like capturing only port 81 on localhost instead of capture all port traffice on localhost).

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

If your site is running on your local machine (127.0.0.1) take a look at the Fiddler [Network configurations](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureFiddler) about

> [monitoring local traffic](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic)

Comment: Both these links seem to have died unfortunately :(